# Problems building DPDK PktGen

Tags: dpdk

I am trying to build DPDK PktGen on Centos 7 using gcc 4.8.5.

I did 'git clone' for dpdk and pktgen:

```
git clone http://dpdk.org/git/dpdk
git clone http://dpdk.org/git/apps/pktgen-dpdk
```

so I understand I have the HEAD revision of each.

I built dpdk using:

```
cd dpdk
meson build
ninja
```

I then tried to build pktgen using:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PWD/meson-private
pkg-config --cflags libdpdk
pkg-config --libs libdpdk
cd $RTE_SDK/pktgen-dpdk
meson build
cd build
ninja
```

but I see numerous errors such as:

```
[76/2153] /usr/bin/meson --internal exe --capture lib/ip_frag.sym_chk -- /data/daldrich/pktgen/dpdk/buildtools/check-symbols.sh /data/daldrich/pktgen/dpdk/lib/librte_ip_frag/version.map lib/librte_ip_frag.a
FAILED: lib/ip_frag.sym_chk
/usr/bin/meson --internal exe --capture lib/ip_frag.sym_chk -- /data/daldrich/pktgen/dpdk/buildtools/check-symbols.sh /data/daldrich/pktgen/dpdk/lib/librte_ip_frag/version.map lib/librte_ip_frag.a
rte_frag_table_del_expired_entries is flagged as experimental
but is not listed in version map
Please add rte_frag_table_del_expired_entries to the version map
```

Are the "Please add xxxx to the version map" messages errors or just warnings?

Should I be using specific hashes of the git repositories?

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally build and install DPDK (with the steps below), but your steps maybe OK, but I have not tested those steps. This is how I build pktgen and DPDK on Ubuntu 20.10, if you can not install DPDK on your system then my steps will not work.

```
cd dpdk
meson build
ninja -C build
sudo ninja -C build install
```

Then build Pktgen.

```
cd ptkgen-dpdk
make rebuild
```

These steps are in the INSTALL or README file. I have not built pktgen on CentOS, your mileage may vary.

The rte_frag_table_XYZ issues are coming from DPDK build system for versioning APIs. The experimental APIs could be disabled in your environment, but normally they should be on unless you turned them off. On some systems packages of DPDK they disable experimental APIs, but you are building from DPDK.org source and should not be a problem.

If the pktgen binary is built then it should work, did the binary get built?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help. By following the INSTALL file carefully and by rebuilding dpdk I got it working.